Find the canonical form of each equation and classify the quadratic curve
I am trying to get this equation to the canonical form using Lagrange Method (completing the squares).
$$5x^2 + 4xy + 8y^2 - 32x - 56y + 80= 0$$
The first step is to get rid of the $4xy$ term, which you can do easily.
After that I get: $$ \left(\sqrt{5}x + \frac {4y}{2 \sqrt{5}}\right)^2 + \frac{36y^2}{5} - 32x - 56y + 80 = 0$$
After this, I do not know how to get rid of the linear terms.

Write the linear terms in terms of $\sqrt 5 x+\frac{2y}{\sqrt 5}$ and $\frac{6y}{\sqrt 5}$. Something like
$$a\left(\sqrt 5 x+\frac{2y}{\sqrt 5}\right)+b\frac{6y}{\sqrt 5}=-32x-56 y$$
Then complete the square for the $\sqrt 5 x+\frac{2y}{\sqrt 5}$ term and then for the $\frac{6y}{\sqrt 5}$ term. You should be left with a constant.
